# Trills + Turns = Water Music

Tags: voice

We are producing a concert with Handel's Water Music Suites and there are a lot
of turns and trills written in the score by Handel. Where is the web page to look at that will explain the right way to play the different trills and the different turns?

Answer (score 1):

Don't bother with statements from "random people on the web" about ornamentation. Most of them are wrong or misguided, just like with everything else on the web!

Look at the relevant chapters in Donington, "The Interpretation of Early Music". It's not up to date with the latest scholarly research (published in the 1960s) but if you are starting from "zero" it's probably got more information than you wanted to know about!

The more general chapters on the baroque period are also a good read.

It's on the web here: https://archive.org/details/interpretationof010975mbp